# .NET Core 2, DI, configuration file

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I am studying .NET Core 2 and I don't like how DI is managed... on the web I read something like the following steps:

1. creating an interface like IService
2. creating an implementation for IService
3. adding it on the scope of .NET Core container into Startup.Configuration method resolving the dependency.
4. finally I can use it into the constructor of my custom controller.

In .NET classic I used a dedicated XML configuration file to manage dependencies: can I use a configuration file (JSON or XML are the same) to do the same I would have to do into Startup.Configuration method?

...otherwise someone can explain me the reason why configure the services into Startup.Configuration is the better way?

Thanks so much...

Comment: *dedicated XML configuration file*? What library were you using for that? There's nothing stopping you writing your own version of that though, sounds pretty simple.

Comment: Can’t you use the same library you were using if that feels better? .NET by itself doesn’t really have DI, Core does have a default implementation but you can use whatever way or library you want for it, as long as it supports Core

Comment: I have not found WindsorCastle for .NET Core... but I mean: I cannot immagine that default DI container for .NET Core is not been thought to be used it with the appsettings.json configuration!! Why I have to do a code-like approach instead of json configuration?

I am just trying to understand... thanks.

Comment: I find it really peculiar that you dislike the normal method that is used for DI. Almost everyone else is happy with it, so what is it that irks you so much?

Comment: Its a difficult question, tending to get you opinion based answers. Configuring dependencies via XML was **always difficult** and prone to errors. When you renamed a class or interface, it did not refactor your Xml Configuration and you had no error until you tried to run the application where it just made pooof... Code based DI Configuration is type safe and gives you compile errors in the IDE when you rename the class (w/o refactor rename) or just do refactor rename and it updates it everywhere.

Comment: On top of that, ASP.NET Core is highly extensible so most extensions and middlewares are meat to be easy plugged in via `services.AddMvc()`-esque style

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, to answer your question "can I use a configuration file", the answer is emphatically "yes". Why shouldn't you is answered later, but for now, here's a poor man's version of how you might do this by adding to your `appsettings.json` file. Note that this code is not optimal, but is designed to show you how you *could* implement this solution.

Let's start with some classes to hold the data:

```cs
public class ServicesConfiguration
{
    public IEnumerable<ServiceItem> Singleton { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ServiceItem> Transient { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceItem
{
    public string Service { get; set; }
    public string Implementation { get; set; }
}
```

Now add a section to your JSON file, you may even want to keep this file external to the main config, but that's an implementation detail I will leave up to you:

```json
{
    //snip main config....

    "Services" : {
        "Singleton": [
            { 
                "Service": "YourNamespace.IFoo1, YourNamespace", 
                "Implementation": "YourNamespace.Foo1, YourNamespace" 
            },   
            {
                "Service": "YourNamespace.IFoo2, YourNamespace", 
                "Implementation": "YourNamespace.Foo2, YourNamespace" 
            }  
        ],
        "Transient": [
            {
                "Service": "YourNamespace.IBar1, YourNamespace",
                "Implementation": "YourNamespace.Bar1, YourNamespace"
            }    
        ]
    }
}
```

And now an extension method to configure it all:

```cs
public static IServiceCollection AddFromConfigurationFile(this IServiceCollection services, 
    IConfigurationSection configuration)
{
    var servicesConfiguration = configuration.Get<ServicesConfiguration>();

    foreach(var service in servicesConfiguration.Singleton)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(Type.GetType(service.Service), Type.GetType(service.Implementation));
    }

    foreach(var service in servicesConfiguration.Transient)
    {
        services.AddTransient(Type.GetType(service.Service), Type.GetType(service.Implementation));
    }

    //Other scopes here...

    return services;
}
```

And call it in `ConifigureServices` like this:

```cs
services.AddFromConfigurationFile(Configuration.GetSection("Services"));
```

So, nice and simple right? Why shouldn't you do this? A few ideas off the top of my head:

1. Why change how almost all DI implementations work? If it ain't broke, why fix it? Just because you are used to a particular method, doesn't mean it's a good idea.
2. Type safety: You lose compile time checking of the types you specify in the configuration file.
3. Security: Having this in a config file would let someone change the implementation to a class of their own choice.

I'm sure there are more, but... it's your app!

Comment: good... I was in searching for an answer like this! thanks a lot!

Comment: Would one "approved" reason to use a configuration file be if I were to use the DI to be able to use different implementations for different "customers"? Let's say I got an "IFileOutput" with two different implementations, one that writes a file to disc and another one that writes it to the cloud (e.g. Azure blob storage). My application is used by multiple customers and each customer has their own instance of my application. With a file based configuration I could easily swap the IFileOutput to either of my implementations depending on my customers' needs.

Comment: @Björn Well I would still prefer a different method for that situation. I'd allow a text file to control which implementation is used, but not which one is registered with DI.

Comment: @DavidG : well I'll be using this technique precisely because I'm selling a product, where some modules are optional.
Thanks for the example, it's exactly what I needed.